# Type alias for Tuple with arbitrary number of elements in Julia

Tags: julia

Type alias for 2dim Tuple in Julia can be defined as

```
const Tuple2f = Tuple{Float64, Float64}
```

In the same manner, 3dim one will be

```
const Tuple3f = Tuple{Float64, Float64, Float64}
```

But how can I define one with an arbitrary number of elements, which cannot be coded directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NTuple` fits your needs, assuming, by your examples, that all elements are of the same type:

```
julia> Threes = NTuple{3, Int}
 Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}

julia> isa((2, 0, 16), Threes)
 true

julia> SoManyFloats{N} = NTuple{N, Float64}
 Tuple{Vararg{Float64,N}} where N

julia> isa((31.0, 33.58), SoManyFloats{2})
 true
```

Answer (score 3):

Julia supports [Vararg Tuple Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Vararg-Tuple-Types-1). You can achieve what you want by making the last parameter of your tuple a `Vararg` type. Here is an example of a `Tuple` type with an arbitrary number of `Float64` parameters.

```
julia> TupleArbf = Tuple{Vararg{Float64}}
Tuple{Vararg{Float64,N} where N}

julia> const Tuple2f = Tuple{Float64, Float64}
Tuple{Float64,Float64}

julia> const Tuple3f = Tuple{Float64, Float64, Float64}
Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64}

julia> a = (1.0, 2.0); b = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);

julia> isa(a, Tuple2f)
true

julia> isa(a, TupleArbf)
true

julia> isa(b, TupleArbf)
true

julia> isa(b, Tuple2f)
false

julia> Tuple2f <: TupleArbf
true

julia> Tuple3f <: TupleArbf
true
```

Note that `Vararg` should be the last parameter of your `Tuple` and the type of parameters before that can be made of any type you want.